# PHP Regular expression with arrows (>>)

Tags: php, regex

I need a little help with my regular expression.

Here is what I've got:

```
function formatLink($post) {
    if(preg_match('/^\>\>[0-9]{+}$/', $post)) {
        return "<font color=\"red\">".$post."</font>";
    } else {
        return "<font color=\"#b7b7b7\">".$post."</font>";  
    }
}
echo formatLink(">>86721678");
```

And honestly I don't know what doesn't it work. It should work for any string like this:

```
>>1

>>87759
```

Very similar to imageboard-like post ref.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. What should it do, what are your testcases, what do you expect for these test cases, what did you get with your current code..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the curly braces. They are not needed. You also need to add the `m` modifier to allow it to match on any line, not just the entire post.

Also note that this will only work if there is literally nothing else on the line, not even a space. You might want to relax it like so:

```
/^\s*>>\s*\d+\s*$/m
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice.

Can you also tell me how can I format text including >>42342 eg.

Hello >>42342 world!

??

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to [escape](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)!

```
<?php
function formatLink($post) {
    if(preg_match('/^\>\>[0-9]{+}$/', $post))
    {
        return "<font color=\"red\">".htmlentities($post)."</font>";
    }
    else
    {
        return "<font color=\"#b7b7b7\">".htmlentities($post)."</font>";  
    }
}

echo formatLink(">>86721678");
```

[Running example](http://3v4l.org/bdnte).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in your regular expression.
Use this instead:

```
if(preg_match('/^\>\>([0-9]+)$/', $post)) {
```

See that I removed the curly brackets from your regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the regex to

```
/^\>\>[0-9]*$/
```