# PHP regex Is this the fastest way to get this result?

Tags: php, regex, string, numbers

Finally I have found the solution to get what I want. The only question is - is this the fastest and best way to change post numbers into linked post numbers?

BTW: I was asking for advice in this thread: [PHP Regular expression with arrows (>>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978332/php-regular-expression-with-arrows)

Maybe someone will find this script useful.

```
$string = "Lorem lipsum >>86721678 texttexttexttexttext >>64356 >234234 9894823 text  gdsfs>>54353<br /><br />";

    preg_match_all('!\>\>\d+!', $string, $matches);
    $nowy = array();
    //getting each number modified
    for ($i=0;$i<count($matches[0]);$i++)
    {
        $nowy[$i] = "<a href=''><font color='red'>".$matches[0][$i]."</font></a>";
    }

    echo str_replace($matches[0], $nowy, $string);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just quick tested, your method is using 5.50746917725E-5 seconds average on my computer.

I tested this because of simplicity and better legibility:

```
echo preg_replace('!\>\>\d+!', "<a href=''><font color='red'>$0</font></a>", $string);
```

its using up 3.00407409668E-5 seconds, So is almost double the speed.

---

**Notes**: You shouldn't focus on the performance on operations like this, unless you are going through very big chunks of data. If it's not human-noticeable it shoud be ok.

In cases like this you should focus on the readability and logic, and how easy it is to mantain and modify this code if you need to in the future, at least that's my opinion

Also if you want better performance testing wrap it all withing a for loop, and loop for 10000 times or whatever you think fits, for example with [microtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) and/or [memory_get_usage()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$string = "Lorem lipsum >>86721678 texttexttexttexttext >>64356 >234234 9894823 text  gdsfs>>54353<br /><br />";

$string = preg_replace_callback("#>>\d+#", "replacewithlinks", $string);
function replacewithlinks($matches)
{

  return "<a href=''><font color='red'>".$matches[0]."</font></a>";
}
echo $string;
?>
```